# Make consistent home url for all sub-sites in WordPress MultiSite Network

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Hy, I need to make my sub-sites in WordPress MultiSite Network to have one home url, mainly for the logo to click and goto the main network site.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
echo network_home_url();
```

---

Or as HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo network_home_url(); ?>">Go to Homepage</a>
```

The function will return the link url so simply put it as href attribute of any anchor tag to make it become a link

Comment: Hi, can you please explain, how exactly will I implement this? if you mean in a child theme for each sub-site then kindly make a snippet that I can use there. Thanks :)

Comment: <a href="<?php echo network_home_url(); ?>">Go to Homepage</a> - The function will return the link url so simply put it as href attribute of any anchor tag to make it become a link

Comment: It would be nice if you could edit your answer instead of writing helpful comments. Future readers will appreciate it.

Comment: Sure no problem